# embed does not open a document in Chrome

Tags: html, web-applications, embed

My Blazor web application needs to display a pdf document. It works in Firefox, but not in chrome. Here is the code:

```
<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,@QuoteModel.Base64EngineeringDrawing" style="overflow:auto;width:800px;height:1000px" />
```

The document is stored in the variable Base64EngineeringDrawing.

Here is how it looks in Firefox:

[image]

But in Chrome it is empty. The inspection shows
[image]

Replacing embed with iframe does not help.

[image]

How can this be fixed?

Comment: @KJ Thank you for your comment. Could you please give me an example with iFrame that would do what embed does in my code? Because just replacing embed with iFrame did not work for me. As you can see, I don't use just a link as src, but an array of bits in a variable...

Comment: @KJ Sorry, I don't get how this can be downloaded.

Comment: @KJ Thanks, that definitely works. But I don't see any difference between your code and mine:

<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,@QuoteModel.Base64EngineeringDrawing" style="overflow:auto;width:800px;height:1000px" />

Can you explain why this does not work?

Comment: My code does work in Firefox.

Comment: @KJ What does the last question mean?

Comment: @KJ I used now 150 KB file (only 4 pages), and also used paired tags, like you said. Instead of having an empty rectangle, I get "Failed to load pdf document" error.

Comment: @KJ Also, I just noticed that this iframe does not work in firefox... And your sample doesn't open in firefox, either...

Comment: If you make this your answer, I will mark is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct use of iFrame is along the lines of

```
<iframe height="500" width="500" src="http://google.com"></iframe>
```

Note the separate terminator that is not the one used for `<embed />`

When using Iframe with embedded datauri: there can be server system and client browser limitations so first test a file under 10KB and then again ensure a test file is under 1.5MB as those can be common hurdles/blockers.

For PDFs especially as application format, every browser handling of PDF data is different depending on html construction and user settings. Hence the recommended method is provide an optional image of preview thumbnail with <a href="filename link" for download as inline viewing is down to the client preferences.

Usually my settings in Edge and other browsers is ask, what to do with incoming PDF

In Firefox on Windows an iFrame with base64 data should offer options like this

[image]

Edge may not offer user control, when its set to default PDF viewer and may display the frame instantly

[image]

If I use Palemoon or Waterfox (Firefox based) the frame is blank as I prefer for most PDF downloads and opens either inline or off line in SumatraPDF (depending on page construction)

[image]

different constructs may behave differently in recent Firefox as there was a security related change around/after version 97.

Comment: <a href="filename link" does not work with base64 pdf data (when the pdf is stored in a variable as an array of bytes). Do you have any sample, by any chance?

Comment: Are you saying <a href="data:application/pdf;base64,@QuoteModel.Base64EngineeringDrawing">Download Engineering Drawing</a> should let the user download the pdf? Or there is something wrong in how I do it? Again, this is Blazor!

Comment: So it is not doable in blazor?